# imwrite a double matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I `imwrite` this value `[12 13.5; 15 107.75]` without changing in `imread`?

I want to save my information. But if I `uint8` this value when I `imread` this matrix, I have this `[12 13; 15 108]`.

Answer (score 2):

(Let `[12 13.5;15 107.75]` be `A`.)

From `imwrite` documentation:

> imwrite(A,filename) writes image data A to the file specified by filename.
>   If A is of data type uint16 and the output file format supports 16-bit data (JPEG, PNG, and TIFF), then imwrite outputs 16-bit values.

So you can multiply `A` by `100` then and then convert it to `uint16`. You will get `[1200 1350;1500 10775]`. Write it to a `(JPEG, PNG, or TIFF)` eg.`imwrite(A,'image.jpeg')`.

Now `imread('image.jpeg')` will return `16-bit` integers. Convert them to double and then divide by `100` to get original data. (eg. `out = double(imread('image.jpeg'))/100` )

**Note:** The highest value representable in 16 bits is `65536`. So this means that you input after scaling up must have numbers less than `65536` or else you will lose information. If you are using doubles `less that 255 with precision 2 or less` (two places after decimal) then the highest value after scaling up would be `25599` which is smaller than `65536` so it is fine. Just take care if your input values have a different range or precision.

Still, I think you should write the data in a file using `fprintf` as suggested by T. Huang.

Comment: @shiva If this helped you then, please select this answer as the accepted answer(by clicking on the tick present right below the answer score counter). It will help others who will come here.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done by imwrite.you may try the fuction fprintf.
http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html